# How to make 2 fields (random string and a date) as index in mongodb, and what complexity would it be to access an element?

Tags: database, mongodb, indexing, time-complexity

The ideal for my project would be to have an index built with 2 fields: `some_key`+`some_date`.
The `some_date` object should contain only the year, month, day, hour, minute.
Is it possible to choose the format of the date object? When trying to create an index with a date object an exception is thrown, saying it's waiting for a number (timestamp I guess), and not a date.

So the documents will look like that:
`{_id: ..., _index: some_key, _date_index: some_date, data: some_data}`

I need the search by `some_date` or `some_key` or both to be very fast.
In this scenario, what would be the search by date complexity?

Is it possible to create such index in Mongo?
What other databases should I consider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB will save a **valid date** in [ISODate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html) format - utc. So you want to make sure your input data is in the correct format. You can then create a compound index on the two fields.

So make sure the data is parsed as a valid date. You can use JavaScript [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) and Date.UTC and construct a date in the format you expect.

1)  insert some data - note the format:

```
db.getCollection("mycollection").insertOne({
    someKey: 'dude',
    someDate: new Date(Date.UTC(2019,12,4,17,0,0))
})
```

[image]

2. Create the index:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { some_date: 1, some_key: 1 }, { name:  'myIndexName' });
```

3. Query and add `explain()`:

```
db.getCollection("mycollection")
   .find({
       someKey: 'dude',
       someDate: new Date(Date.UTC(2019,12,4,17,0,0))
   })
   .explain();
```

You will see the winning plan is using your index.

Comment: Thanks ! great! Is there a way to add some conditions on the date query? for example month is between 10 and 12? Do you have any idea about the complexity?

Comment: Look at the [query operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/) `db.getCollection("mycollection").find({
    someKey: 'dude',
    someDate: { $gte:ISODate("2019-12-04 17:00"), $lt:ISODate("2019-12-04 18:00") }
});`

Comment: Samuel, the point 1. doesnt work.  trying to do (in Java): collection.createIndex(new BasicDBObject().append("_date_index", new Date())); and I get an error: Values in v:2 index key pattern cannot be of type date. Only numbers > 0, numbers < 0, and strings are allowed.

Comment: You are trying to specify an actual `Date()` instance as a parameter when creating the index and not sure why you would do that. The options are either `1` or `-1` to indicate if the index should be ascending or descending. [Docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/) are your friend.

Comment: @Upsilon42 did you resolve that index creation? Please remember to accept the answer if it solved your problem.